# Create and Write PDF Webdev

Tags: windev

I want to create and write in file's PDF.

my code :

```
fCrée("C:\Mes Sites\COBRA_22\Courrier\test.pdf")
fOuvre("C:\Mes Sites\COBRA_22\Courrier\test.pdf",foAjout)
fSauveTexte("C:\Mes Sites\COBRA_22\Courrier\test.pdf","ok")
```

But this code does'nt work !

Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This functions are not for create a PDF, you must look into this [documentation](http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?1011091) for create a PDF from a report with windev.

Answer (score 0):

As sayed Bidjes answer the easiest way to create pdf is to use report,

you'll have to create fields into your report an link them to a database or global variables.

here's an example (with global variables) :

***Report :***
[image: The report]

***English Version :***

```
gsHeader = "This is a title !"
gsBody = "This is a simple text."
iPreview(iPDF, "PATH_AND_NAME.pdf")
iPrintReport(REPORT_test)
```

***French version :***

```
gsTitre = "C'est un titre !"
gsContenu = "C'est un simple texte."
iAperçu(iPDF, "CHEMIN_ET_NOM.pdf")
iImprimeEtat(ETAT_test)
```

**Result :**
[image: The pdf created]